# Finding all circular primes below a given number in python

Tags: python, primes

I'm trying to write a piece of code that's going to print out all the circular primes below a given number, but for some reason my code is printing numbers that are way above my limit. Do you see any possible way it can be fixed?

```
from collections import deque
def gen_primes(upper):

    D = {}
    q = 2
    while q <= upper:
        if q not in D:
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]
        else:
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]       
        q += 1 

def next_largest(n):
    k = len(str(n))
    return 10**k

def circular_primes(upper):
    circular = [] 

    primes = list(gen_primes(next_largest(upper)))  

    for prime in primes:
        string = str(prime)
        digits = deque(string)

        for rotation in range(1, upper):
            digits.rotate(1)

            if int("".join(digits)) not in primes:
                break
        else:
            circular.append(prime)

    return circular

print(circular_primes(200))
```

output

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, 97, 113, 131, 197, 199, 311, 337, 373, 719, 733, 919, 
971, 991]
```

Comment: You are defining `next_largest` as 10**3 == 1000, so you get all primes up till 1000

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the primes variable initialization

```
primes = list(gen_primes(upper))
```

next_largest function is returning the value 1000 for 200 as 10**3.

```
def next_largest(n):
    k = len(str(n))
    return 10**k
```

Comment: by changing doing that, not all circular primes at being checked and so if upper= 200 it only shows the first 13 primes

Comment: Yes. That's what you want right? You want to find out all the circular primes from 1 to 200 (upper)?